# Types of users in - VM, Cluster, microservice application

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, identity

I am trying to understand all types of users available in any machine with a microservice apps runnning on it.
My assumptions:

- Virtual Machine - it will have its own users
- Clusters on VM(s) - Cluster will have its own users. Are they different from VM users?
- Microservice applications running on these cluster - these app may have their own users. Are they different from Cluster and VM users?

Feel free to correct my assumptions and add more details to this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- VM - will indeed have its own users
- Clusters on VM(s) - A cluster is just a bunch of machines that k8's can use to run containers on. Nothing special there. K8s has its own users that is on a cluster level. (service account, users etc) seperate from the VM users. K8's manages what those users can do to the cluster. Creating a pod for example.
- Microservice applications - If youre talking about containers yes. They run their own users within the container. What user those containers can use can be enforced on a k8's level. (disallowing root for example)

So at each level its separate users

You can unify all of these separate users using something like AD. Your VM users are users on AD. Users that can access the cluster can be AD users and users in containers can be AD users if the container is joined to the domain (hard).